# Haskell reading matrix from a list in file and use it

Tags: list, haskell, matrix, io

I need to get a Matrix from a list in file. Example:

file.txt:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

I want to read it in this form: `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]`.

Moreover, I need to manipulate it in another function like:

```
func m x y = do{ printMatrix m; 
    return $ m !! x !! y;
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Good news, it is indeed possible! That was an easy question. If you want to know more about *how* to do it, it would help to have more detail about the input files you need to use.

Answer (score 5):

There is the rather naive way of using nested lists for your matrix. If your input is already in this Haskellish form, you can also use the function `read` to parse the input. For example:

```
type Matrix a = [[a]]

readMatrix :: FilePath -> IO (Matrix a)
readMatrix path = f <- getFile path
                  return $ read f

elemAt :: Int -> Int -> Matrix a -> a
elemAt x y m = m !! x !! y

-- and so on
```

Answer (score 2):

a solution could be:

```
l2m ::(Eq a) ⇒ Int → [a] → [[a]]
l2m rsize as
    | rsize ≡ 0 = []
    | as ≡ [] = []
    | otherwise = [(take rsize as)] ++ l2m rsize (drop rsize as)

aij :: (Eq a) ⇒ Int → Int → [[a]] → a
aij i j as = (as !! (i - 1)) !! (j - 1)
```

to use this function you will have to get your input to a (Eq a) => [a].
hope this helps ε/2